# How do I try parsing two different possible date formats?

Tags: python, date

I have a field in a dataset that has multiple data types allowed. I'm trying to identify whether or not the field value begins with a date, in the format of `MM/DD/YYYY` or `MM/DD/YY`.

I'm struggling to figure out how to accommodate for both. Here's what I've come up with so far:

```
import datetime

data = ['09/01/2020', '8/1/20 Valid string', '10/2/21']

for date in data:
    try:
        if date.find(' ') == -1:
            try:
                due_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%Y")
            except Exception as err:
                due_date = ''
        else:
            due_date = date[:date.find(' ')]
            due_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%Y")
    except Exception as err:
        due_date = ''
```

So the above works for just the first date format, but obviously ignoring the other second date format. What's the appropriate Pythonic way to parse both possible date formats?

Comment: Well given that it's simply impossible to decide what date `4/4/2020` is without more context this is clearly impossible without guessing. You can try the first one and do the second one in the catch block of the first conversion.

Comment: @Voo: The question is about whether the year is given as two digits or four.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all dates follow the pattern: month/day/year and the strings are starting with the date, you could do something like this:

```
import datetime

data = ['09/01/2020', '8/1/20 Valid string', '10/2/21']

for date in data:
    date = date.split(' ')[0]  # split off everything afer the first space
    # 'normalize' days and months to keep a leading zero
    date = ['0%s' % int(datePart) if int(datePart) < 10 else datePart for datePart in date.split('/')]
    # normalize year, 4 digits
    date[-1] = date[-1] if len(date[-1]) == 4 else '20' + date[-1]
    due_date = datetime.datetime.strptime('/'.join(date), "%m/%d/%Y")
    print(due_date)
```

Out:

```
2020-09-01 00:00:00
2020-08-01 00:00:00
2021-10-02 00:00:00
```